# How to connect pre-build HTML Form to a database using Ruby?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I know that with ruby you can use the scaffolding command, and it'll make the html form for you. But i already create the HTML Form manually, and i don't know how to connect your existing HTML Form to a database using Ruby. I create the HTML around Bootstrap framework, and place the form within a Modal.

Here is a snippet of my HTML Form:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="signModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h6 class="modal-title2">Sign Up Form</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="InputEmail">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-inline" id="InputEmail" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="InputFirst">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-inline" id="InputFirst" placeholder="First Name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="InputLast">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-inline" id="InputLast" placeholder="Last Name">
          </div>
        </form>
        <label for="mobilePhone">Mobile Phone</label>
        <form class="form-inline">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="mobilePhone" placeholder="Mobile Phone">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control">
              <option>Android</option>
              <option>iOS</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div class="formButton">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div> <!-- End Modal -->
```

I'm still new to Ruby. Hope i explained my question well. Thanks a bunch! :D

Comment: Either way, you have work ahead of you to rework what you have already done. Why don't you start with a simple scaffolding form and study it, perhaps extending your scaffolding to build up your final form and factor over what you want from your pre-scaffolding form?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use rails form or simple form gem to convert your form. Please check rails guide or simple form documentation for details.